# Can't assign remote_image_url carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, image-uploading, fb-graph

So I'm using the fb_graph gem to pull data from facebook to create new events within my application. Trouble is, I can't seem to use remote_image_url to get the picture to upload via carrierwave.  Here's the code from organization.rb:

```
  page = FbGraph::Page.fetch(uri, :access_token => token)
  org_events = page.events({:fields => "name,description,picture,id,location,start_time"})
  org_events.each do |event|
    Event.create!(
        :name => event.name,
        :description => event.description,
        :location => event.location,
        :date =>event.start_time ,
        :time => event.start_time,
        :organization_id => self.id,
        :remote_image_url => event.picture  #broken code
    )
  end
```

And here's the mounted uploader and image attribute from the top of the model:

```
attr_accessible :image
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

This is the error message I'm running into--

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: remote_image_url
```

Comment: Are you using a gem such as `protected_attributes`?

Comment: Not at the moment--should I be?

Comment: Could you show the `Event` model? If you are using Rails 4, the `mass-assign protected attributes` is a common error while migration.

Comment: Worked it out--I had to add attr_accessible :remote_image_url to the Event model

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  org_events.each do |event|
   myEvent = Event.new(
    :name => event.name,
    :description => event.description,
    :location => event.location,
    :date =>event.start_time ,
    :time => event.start_time,
    :organization_id => self.id
  )
  myEvent.remote_image_url = event.picture
  myEvent.save!
  myEvent
 end
```

we are using myEvent.remote_image_url , because remote_image_url is a helper method